# VB.NET: Operator '=' is not defined ... for a variable and object of THE SAME TYPE?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Okay, I am TOTALLY confused here. I have a class... say `MyClass`. It has several properties of another class of my type, say `MyHelperClass` (along with other properties).

I am doing the following:

```
Dim inst As MyClass = New MyClass() With {
    .p1 = sv1, 
    .p2 = sv2, 
    .h1 = getHelperClass(a1), 
    .p3 = sv3, 
    .p4 = sv4, 
    .h2 = getHelperClass(a2), 
    .p5 = sv5, 
    ...
    .pN = svN
}
```

*where .p# is some property, .sv# is some valid value. .h# is a property of type `MyHelperClass` and getHelperClass(a#) returns an instance of said class.

Now, I have the odd thing here, where the assignment statement for h1 works perfect. No problems. The assignment statement for h2 however, it is giving me the following blue-squiggle error:

`Operator '=' is not defined for types myLib.MyHelperClass and myLib.MyHelperClass.`

I just do not get this error at all! I don't even know where to start to figure this out. HELP!

**201105.06 0305:** 
The signature for h1's type is `List(Of myLib.Address)`, where `Address` is a very basic class with typical address fields (name, address, city, state, zip, etc.). The return type of `getHelperClass` is also `List(Of myLib.Address)`.

As SSS hinted at in his answer, I would expect `=` to not work in the "natural" way if I was using it for equality testing on a class without operators, however I am using it as an assignment operator, not equality, which I can't see any problem with. I am expecting the result of `getHelperClass` to be assigned to h2. But instead it's telling me `=` is not defined for the type. Is it possible that for some reason, the compiler is interpreting it as `=(EQUALS)` instead of `=(ASSIGN)`?

As for commenting out that line and it happening on the first one, I'll need to wait till I'm back in the office tomorrow to check that. Will report back.

Comment: Can you post the signature of the `MyClass` field `h1`?

Comment: This article is a bit light on information that would help us better diagnose the issue.  Can you provide us with some of the code for the MyHelperClass?  Also, if you comment out the .h2 line, does the application compile or does it then pass the error up to the previous assignment?

Comment: Updated with some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, yeah, sorry didn't read your OP properly. The assignment must be being misinterpreted as an comparison. Maybe you are missing a comma? For example in the statement "a = b = c" the first equals sign is an assignment, the second is a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Operator methods to MyHelperClass

e.g.

```
Public Shared Operator =(byval a as MyHelperClass, byval b as MyHelperClass) As Boolean
...
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(byval a as MyHelperClass, byval b as MyHelperClass) As Boolean
...
End Operator
```

You should also read up on the difference between Reference and Value types.

Comment: This would make sense, ... except that the assignment of h1 works fine, without any error, while h2 doesn't they are the same exact type, assigned in exactly the same way. That's what really throws me. I know `=(EQUALS)` differs from value to reference types. But I am not using `=(EQUALS)`, I am using `=(ASSIGN)` (true, VB can be unclear, using `=` for both, unlike the C-style languages with `=` vs. `==`).

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry didn't read your OP properly. The assignment must be being misinterpreted as an assignment. Maybe you are missing a comma? For example in the statement "a = b = c" the first equals sign is an assignment, the second is a comparison.

Comment: Yeah, missing two sets of closing parens. Which it was not giving the usual blue squiggle that I would've expected in that case. Ahhhh, crazy compiler. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept and give you the rep.